# How to create a cropped and centered image with Imagemagick's command line options with variant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a Ruby on Rails 5.2 RC2 app that uses [ActiveStorage](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) for hosting images. In particular it's [transforming images](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images) with [variant](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html).

I would like to pass an image, typically of 16:9 or 4:3 ratio and have `variant` crop it to a specific ratio, width x height, and have it centered. The image could be horizontal or vertical, but the new cropped size is centered.

[image: Image Cropping]

From the [Imagemagick Command Line Options documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php), I have the following:

`<%= image_tag @photo.image.variant(extent: "1:1", crop: "800x800").processed.service_url %>`

It creates a square crop, but it's not centered. It defaults to the left. **How do I create a cropped image that's centered with Imagemagick's command line option?**

I'm looking for a solution that should work on any image size or aspect ratio. I believe any resizing works off of the originally uploaded image for creation.

For reference, I'm looking to upgrade an older Rails app that uses [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave). There is a `resize_to_fill` that does exactly that. Example code:

`version :square_thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [200,200]
 end`

Answer (score 9):

Use [`combine_options`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/variation.rb#L13-L17) to pass the `gravity` and `crop` options to ImageMagick’s `mogrify` utility simultaneously:

```
@photo.image.variant(combine_options: { gravity: "center", crop: "800x800" })
```

You should also avoid processing the variant directly in the view, as it blocks rendering.

Comment: This is very close. I did not know that of combine_options, thanks to link in actual source code. I find the following to yield the best results: @photo.image.variant(combine_options: { crop: "4:3", resize: "800x600", gravity: "center" }). Order does matter as I've tried different orderings. If you update your answer to include this I will accept it.

Comment: I'm using this for square thumbnails: `@photo.image.variant(combine_options: {thumbnail: '200x200^', gravity: 'center', extent: '200x200'})`. It works well, but I didn't try it with variable aspect ratio.

Comment: The answer doesn't work for me: it raises an `Errno::ENOENT in ActiveStorage::RepresentationsController#show`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a gravity setting somewhere. In the command line it would be -gravity center.

Extent extends the canvas and I do not think you need that

Try:

```
gravity: "center", crop: "800x800"
```

Comment: I've tried setting the gravity and it doesn't work. I get the error: "No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /var/folders/cp/h7rhtqxn00x8z5tjcnr7lp300000gn/T/mini_magick20180405-1235-171hqy6.jpg". The error only comes up when the gravity option is set.